# Как в mozilla firefox поменять все стили тега <audio>

Tags: javascript, html, css

Конкретно нужно убрать вот этот черный бэкграунд, от слова совсем, он по дефолту черный и цвет bg только накладывается на него. Перелопатил гугл, но ничего полезного кроме webkit для chrome не нашел, а -moz- не работает для этого тега. Тут нужен совет опытных людей.[![введите сюда описание изображения][1]][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5i5PO.png`<audio controls="">
                        <source src="/upload/iblock/2c8/2c85b60cdb5b983786b9458b828dda10.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
                    </audio>`

Comment: Не париться, скрыть audio и сверстать свой плеер с управлением через javascript (впрочем, с его написанием придётся повозиться)

Comment: Да, это единственный походу вариант. Спасибо.